# Jacoco has a missing branch on a safe call with an elvis operator in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, jacoco

N.B. please check the GitHub issue I've raised on this, and give it a like, so we can gain some traction to get it fixed.

Here's some code:

```
data class House(val line1: String)
data class Street(val house: House)
fun mapCheck(key : String) : House {

    val map = mapOf("A" to Street(House("10 London Road")))

    val street = map[key]
    return street?.house ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("unknown key")

}
```

and here's a test for it (using Kotest and Junit 5)

```
 @Test
fun mapTest() {
    val factory = dpsServiceFactory()
    factory.mapCheck("A").line1 shouldBe "10 London Road"
    shouldThrow<java.lang.IllegalArgumentException> { factory.mapCheck("V")  }
}
```

For this line `return street?.house ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("unknown key")` my jacoco coverage report says I only have 3 out of 4 conditions covered.

I'm confused by this. I can only see two conditions, the two I have catered for in the test. What's the condition I'm not testing for ?

Update - this only occurs in Kotlin 1.7.10, Jacoco reports full coverage in Kotlin 1.6.10.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code with `JaCoCo: 0.8.8, Kotest: 5.1.0, Kotlin: 1.6.10, JDK: 11.0.12`.
The report indicates that all 4 branches covered with 100%. Your test should cover all cases. I don't know why our results differ.

**JaCoCo Branches**

> "JaCoCo also calculates branch coverage for all `if` and `switch` statements. This metric counts the total number of such branches in a method and determines the number of executed or missed branches."

https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/counters.html

*Your code under test is *

```kotlin
return street?.house ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("unknown key")
```

When we decompile it, it would be like the code as follows.

```java
if (street != null) { // Branch (1)
     House var10000 = street.getHouse();
     if (var10000 != null) { // Branch (3)
            return var10000;
     } 
     else { // Branch (4)
     }
}
else { // Branch (2)
}

throw (Throwable)(new IllegalArgumentException("unknown key"));
```

JaCoCo counts all branches and all missed branches. Empty `else` branches are not considered missed.

Comment: Do branches 3 and 4 still exist even though Kotlin guarantees that var10000 will be non-null (because Street contains non-nullable `House` and not `House?`)?

Comment: An `if` statement automatically counts 2. There two if statements, so branch count is 4. JaCoCo works on generated byte code but not on actual code written in `Kotlin` or `Java`.

Comment: You're right. I'm disappointed to learn that Kotlin emits the bytecode for `if (var10000 != null)` even though it knows it's always going to be true (and therefore the `if` is unnecessary).

Comment: I'm not sure what version of jacoco I'm on; I'll try it with the version given in the answer when I'm back at work and if it works I'll mark this answer as correct. Thanks.

Comment: Changing the Kotlin version to 1.6.10 fixes the issue; it looks like a bug in Jacoco if you use 1.7.10 (which is what I was using initially)

Comment: Same bug if you use 1.6.21 of Kotlin.

I've raised a bug report:

https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/1351